# ultrasonic sensor stops after giving some reading when running in thread on tornado websocket python

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket, raspberry-pi, tornado

I am using a Raspberry Pi to read an ultrasonic sensor using a Python script.

When I am running the Python scripts independently, it's reading continuously, because I am calling `get_ultra` function in a while loop.
But when I am calling `get_ultra` function in while loop on a Python Tornado WebSocket server using threading, it stops reading after a few readings.

Here is my `ultrasonic.py` file code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

def get_ultra():

    global componentconfig

    GPIO_TRIGGER = 26
    GPIO_ECHO    = 26
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setup(GPIO_TRIGGER,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, False)

    time.sleep(0.01)

    GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, True)
    time.sleep(0.00001)
    GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, False)
    start = time.time()
    GPIO.setup(GPIO_ECHO,GPIO.IN)

    while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO)==0:
        start = time.time()

    while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO)==1:
        stop = time.time()

    elapsed = stop - start

    distance = elapsed * 34300
    distance = distance / 2
    distance1 = "%.2f" % distance
    print "ultra sonic distance" , distance1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while 1:
        get_ultra()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Here is my Tornado WebSocket server:

```
import time
import thread
import traceback
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket
import ultrasonic

def Ultrasonic(T_name,a):

    while 1:
        ultrasonic.get_ultra()
        time.sleep(0.0038)


class ServerHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

    def check_origin(self, origin):

        return True

    def open(self):

        print"Connection open"

    def on_close(self):

        print"Connection close"

    def on_message(self,message):

        print message
        if message=="start":
             t12=threading.Thread(target=Ultrasonic,args('ultrasonic', 0 ))
             t12.setDaemon(True)
             t12.start()

if __name__=="__main__":

    tornado.options.parse_command_line()

    app=tornado.web.Application(handlers=[(r"/",ServerHandler)])

    server=tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)

    app.listen(9001)

    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Note: Within the `t12` thread, I am calling ten another threads, which I did not mention here. I think I may have a memory leak there.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are trying to run blocked thread, try to start async thread like this:

```
t12=threading.Thread(target=Ultrasonic,args=('ultrasonic', 0,))
t12.start()
```